# Get List of Accounts of duplicate Contacts

Tags: apex, soql

**Requirement:**

A component that displays duplicate Contacts (having the same Name) *along with the Account each of those Contacts is linked to*.

**Here is my current query:**

```
[SELECT Name, count(Id), Account.Name FROM Contact GROUP BY Name HAVING count(Id)>1];
```

Basically, it's using an aggregate function to find the duplicate Contacts and then traversing to Account.Name in the query

**But this isn't working. Error message in console:**

```
duplicate alias: Name
```

I suspect this is because the parser can't distinguish between the Contact.Name and the Account.Name field in our query. Since, according my understanding, using AS isn't possible for fields, only for tables in SOQL, I'm at the end of my latin.

**Anybody has an idea how to resolve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are selecting `Account.Name` field without grouping it. You either have to group it or you have to aggregate it.

So basically, this below code should suffice your needs

```
Set<string> setNames = new Set<string>();
for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT  Name, count(Id) ContactCount FROM Contact GROUP BY Name HAVING count(Id)>1]){
    setNames.add(string.valueOf(ar.get('Name')));
}

List<Contact> dupContacts = [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Name IN :setNames order by Name];
```

Comment: Thanks VIjay. I see what you're doing and it's a highly intelligent idea,

but that part "as per your requirement, you want to get the duplicate Contacts under same Account" isn't true: I want to get all accounts of a duplicate-contact-group. 

As each of the contacts might have a different account (perhaps the Contact works for several companies), but they're still duplicates.

Comment: Ok, got you.. Updated the answer, that should work for you.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you Sir.

(to someone else reading: replace "put" with "add", but that was just a minor typo in otherwise brilliant thinking)

Comment: My pleasure !! and thanks for the observation  !! Corrected it :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes SOQL and Apex error messages are rather unintuitive.

I think here the "real" issue is that you're trying to `SELECT` a field (`Account.Name`) you neither group nor aggregate in your query. You cannot do that using Aggregate SOQL; each field you `SELECT` must either by aggregated (`count(Id)`) or `GROUP`ed `BY` (`Name`). Note that each duplicate-group of Contacts may be on different Accounts!

You'd need to run this query to generate a `List<AggregateResult>` and then iterate over your results to accumulate a `Set<String>` of the duplicate `Name` fields. You'd need to then run a non-aggregate SOQL query along the lines of

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Name IN :nameSet
```

to pull back the actual results you can display.